# How to dynamically substitute a string in excel using relations?

Tags: excel

I have a formula made of components and a table of components that translates each component to several strings.
I want to substitute each component with the expression of the sum of the respective strings in the table.

Example:
Formula = FOO/BAR
Table:

```
+-----------+---------+
| Component | Strings |
+-----------+---------+
| FOO       |     1.1 |
| FOO       |     1.2 |
| FOO       |     1.3 |
| FOO       |     5.1 |
| BAR       |  101.10 |
| BAR       |  101.15 |
| BAR       |    5.10 |
+-----------+---------+
```

Result: (1.1+1.2+1.3+5.1)/(101.10+101.15+5.10)

Edit: I need the expression printed not the result of the calculation.
I think the solution probably envolves the function substitute.

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have written a quick dirty UDF to give you the idea how it can be done.

Put this code inside module and write FTEXT in any cell and give parameters.

[image]

```
Function test(Ref As Range, para1 As String) As String
    Dim Cell As Range
    Dim temp1 As String
    Dim temp2 As String

    For Each Cell In Ref
        If Cell.Value = para1 Then
            temp1 = temp1 & Cell.Offset(, 1).Value & "+"
        Else
            temp2 = temp2 & Cell.Offset(, 1).Value & "+"
        End If
    Next Cell

    test = "(" + Left(temp1, Len(temp1) - 1) + ")" + "/" + "(" + Left(temp2, Len(temp2) - 1) + ")"
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your data is in `A2:B8` then following formula can do this.

`=SUMIF(A2:A8,"FOO",B2:B8)/SUMIF(A2:A8,"BAR",B2:B8)`

Is that what you want?

Comment: No I don't want the result of the operation, I want the string (1.1+1.2+1.3+5.1)/(101.10+101.15+5.10) printed not the result of it